# Sending Bulk Mail with phpMailer

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I am creating a mailing list service for a specific group. The recipients are set for double-opt-in, and all mails have an unsubscribe link.

The mailing list of recipients is stored in a database table, and there is a template used for the mailing. Mails are created by looping through the recipient table, then using phpMailer to send out the mail on SMTP port 465 with authentication. The 'from' address is set to noreply@mydomain.com. The site is on a shared host. The to address is cleared in the loop by `$mail->clearAllAddresses()` . Sample small mailings (under 50 recipients) work fine, so the code loop works properly

The mailing process is initiated by the owner of the mailing list, an authenticated user on the site. They select a template, and a mailing list, and the list is built and sent out.  Recipient count can be as high as 10,000. (Again, double-opt-in list of recipients, so not spam mailings.)

My concern is rate limiting. I can put a delay of 1-2 seconds in the loop that sends the phpMailer mail command, but will the page that initiates the mail sending time out before all mails are sent? This may not be a problem with smaller recipient lists, but will there be an issue with large lists?

I could put the mailing into a separate table and CRON the mail sending. But will the browser-initiated mailing time out with large lists? Or is another technique indicated?

Comment: `will the browser-initiated mailing time out with large lists`...depends on your timeout settings. But probably yes. And if it fails, it's harder to restart the job. This is definitely something that cron should be handling. Or just use something like mailman, if you can.

Comment: I run postfix on my servers which has an option to throttle the outbound mail. This makes the PHP side much easier: run it as fast as it will go,, dumping the messages in the outbound queue for postfix to handle. Will this timeout? How fast is your computer? How long are your lists?

Comment: [The PHPMailer docs are your friend](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Sending-to-lists). Using those techniques I have no trouble sending up to around 250 messages *per second* (yes, that's 10k in 40 seconds) using PHPMailer. Don't try to send large volumes based off page loads, it's just the wrong tools for the job. Either trigger batches from cron (as other suggested), or use a long-running process, and *definitely* send via a local mail server, which will deal with all the queuing, greylisting, retries, bounces, etc.